# migrate a vm from vmware workstation 9 to vmware server 4

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-server

I have a case where we have  VM that was initially created on VMWare Workstation 9.  This VM is going to go production, so now we need to load it into our VMWare Server.  The problem is that the VMWare server is version 4.0.  I cannot seem to just load the vm from workstation (newer file format).

Is there a way to migrate this VM from a newer version of VMWare workstation to an older version of VMWare server?

Comment: VMware Server? Do you mean ESXi/vSphere?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest option is to use a copy of VMware converter, specify the local VM as the source and the ESXi server as the destination.

This will allow you to downgrade the vmware hardware version pretty readily.

For reference see [VMware KB 1028019](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1028019)